# How to calculate the amount of combinations?

Tags: combinations

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the amount of combinations some products can make.

I have 8700 products, each can come with ANY of the following.

20 different Ribbons

10 different Discs

5 different Cases

For each product, a ribbon, disc and case must be chosen.

How can I calculate how many combinations are possible?

Comment: Why not just multiply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways of selecting a ribbon,disc,case are $20,10,5$ so total ways are $20.10.5=1000$ this is for 1 so for $8700$ there are $870k$